# How can you bind an Indexed property to a control in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, properties, indexer

Given an instance of the class ThisClassShouldBeTheDataContext as the Datacontext for the view

```cs
class ThisClassShouldBeTheDataContext
{
  public Contacts Contacts {get;set;}
}

class Contacts
{
  public IEnumerable<Person> Persons {get;set;}
  public Person this[string Name]
  {
    get 
    {
      var p = from i in Persons where i.Name = Name select i;
      return p.First();
    }    
  }
}

class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string PhoneNumber {get;set;}
}
```

How can I bind `Contact["John"].PhoneNumber` to a textbox?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ?????}" />
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The indexer notation is basically the same as C#:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Contacts[John].PhoneNumber}" />
```

See [Binding Declarations Overview > Binding Path Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.100).aspx#Path_Syntax) in MSDN for more info.

This won't, of course, work for arbitrary data types...

Comment: What if my index is not a string, or it's from another property from the vm, say {Binding Contacts[ThisIsAnotherPropertyFromTheVm].PhoneNumber}. How can I do that?

Comment: It's been years since I asked the question in the comment when I was starting to use WPF, now I'm gonna answer it. I think the best way to do this is not to bind to an indexed property. Just expose another property where the getter will return the indexed property (i.e Contacts[ThisIsAnotherPropertyFromTheVm].PhoneNumber)