# In WPF, is it possible to bind values to controls in a loop?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a series of TextBlock Controls, like this:

```
<TextBox Name="tb1"/>
<TextBox Name="tb2"/>
<TextBox Name="tb3"/>
<TextBox Name="tb4"/>
```

And I have a list of values that I'd like to bind to those text boxes, say in a list:

```
List<String> texts = new List<String>();
texts.Add("test1");
texts.Add("test2");
texts.Add("test3");
texts.Add("test4");
```

Currently, what I have to do is manually set the values of the TextBoxes, like this:

```
tb1.Text = texts[0];
tb2.Text = texts[1];
tb3.Text = texts[2];
tb4.Text = texts[3];
```

Is it possible to do this in a loop somehow? Perhaps change the XAML to take in a list or programatically get the TextBoxes? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<ItemsControl Items="{Binding myValues}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding}"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In your code behind declare a property:

```
public string myValues { get return new[] { "foo", "bar" }; }
```

and in the code behind constructor set this control to its datacontext:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Hmmm, gives me "Exception: Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."

Answer (score 0):

You can access indexed values in your binding - no loop required. Check this [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671376/how-can-you-bind-an-indexed-property-to-a-control-in-wpf/1671389#1671389) from [Ivan Towlson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/61700/itowlson). Ivan uses a string indexer in that example, but you can use a numeric one as well.