# Create a media element in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, binding, mediaelement

I am trying to create a media element in my windows 8 app.

I have a media element in my XAML page

```
 <MediaElement Source="Assets/test.wmv"/>
```

This works, but instead of placing the source uri directly in the XAML, I would like to Bind to it.

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding Videos}"/>
```

Where "Videos" is defined in the code behind the XAML page, ie, the XAML cs file.

```
this.DefaultViewModel["Video"]="Assets/test.wmv";
```

This doesn't work. How do I set the source of the video?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671376/how-can-you-bind-an-indexed-property-to-a-control-in-wpf) should help.

Comment: Have you set your datacontext?