# c# Bind to indexed property in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have seen many examples on how to bind in xaml to a indexed property like sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671376/how-can-you-bind-an-indexed-property-to-a-control-in-wpf). And it is easy to create a binding in code like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx), really straight forward, but what about binding in code to a indexed property? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same exact way:

```
  Binding myBinding = new Binding("Contacts[John].PhoneNumber");
  myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

The `Path` you use doesn't change between setting in XAML and setting in Code-Behind.

Comment: Note, you should almost *never* need to do this, bindings *belong* in XAML, but it is the exact same.

Comment: Pretty cool, i will give it a go tomorrow first thing in the morning and set as the correct answer if it works. Thanks @BradleyDotNET

Comment: Sure, i understand that, it just makes sense on the project i am working on. Thanks

Comment: @BrunoPiresLavigneQuintanilh I figured you probably did, but I though it needed *some* disclaimer for future readers if nothing else.