# Composition of WPF Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, composition

I want to create a WPF control that allows to manipulate specific bits in a Byte (the markup is attached to the bottom of this post).

It should be used as follows

```
<ns:BitManipulator BitByte={Binding Path=...} />
```

but I cannot figure out how to organise (Multi-)Bindings to keep the following three values the same:
a) Byte-Value in the Model that BitByte will be bound to
b) Byte-Value of BitByte which either should update its value if either the model's value or the BitVector's value changes
c) Bit-Representation of BitByte in the TextBoxes named *order_i*

Any hint appreciated

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfLib.StackOverflow.BitManipulator"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Name="order_0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox Name="order_1" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBox Name="order_2" Grid.Column="2" />
        <TextBox Name="order_3" Grid.Column="3" />
        <TextBox Name="order_4" Grid.Column="4" />
        <TextBox Name="order_5" Grid.Column="5" />
        <TextBox Name="order_6" Grid.Column="6" />
        <TextBox Name="order_8" Grid.Column="7" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**C# Code behind**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfLib.StackOverflow
{
    [ContentProperty("BitByte")]
    public partial class BitManipulator : UserControl
    {
        public static DependencyProperty BitByteProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register
            (
                "BitByte", 
                typeof(Byte), 
                typeof(BitManipulator), 
                new PropertyMetadata(null)
            );

        public BitManipulator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Byte BitByte
        {
            get { return (Byte)GetValue(BitByteProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BitByteProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for quite time. But it seems that there is mistake on MSDN at *CollectionChanged* event and it's not firing for individual items changes.
For sketch of your case I'll just leave some sample.
XAML for bindable collection of textboxes

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bits}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

BindableBit class for individual items to fire changes to the upper level.

```
public class BindableBit : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        private int bit;
        private readonly int index;
        public Action<int, int> ChangedAction;

        public int Value {
            get { return bit; }
            set {
                bit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                if (ChangedAction != null) ChangedAction(index, bit);
            }
        }

        public BindableBit(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        ...PropertyChangedImplementation
    }
```

MainCode where we create base representation in bits and then change *myByte* value on every change from inside the *collection*.

```
public partial class MyCustomBitsControl: UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private byte myByte;

    private readonly List<BindableBit> collection;
    public List<BindableBit> Bits {
        get { return collection; }
    }

    public MyCustomBitsControl() {
        const byte defaultValue = 7;
        myByte = defaultValue;
        var index = 0;
        collection = new BitArray(new[] { myByte }).Cast<bool>()
            .Select(b => new BindableBit(index++) { Value = (b ? 1 : 0), ChangedAction = ChangedAction }).Reverse().ToList();

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void ChangedAction(int index, int value) {
        var bit = (byte)Math.Pow(2, index);
        if (value == 0) {
            myByte &= (byte)(byte.MaxValue - bit);
        }
        else {
            myByte |= bit;
        }
    }

    ...PropertyChangedImplementation
    }
```

After implementing dependency property you can get needed values from both the *myByte* field, or *collection*. Just reinitialize the *collection* on *setValues* like we've done in curent *constructor*. All changes will appear at UI(don't forget to *notify* for that change or modify its type to *observableCollection*).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that uses [binding to indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671389/3745022) that is defined on the control itself:

## User control code-behind

Here the `UserControl` itself implements indexer property and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (to allow [notification about the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657675/propertychanged-for-indexer-property) in the indexer property).

```
[ContentProperty("BitByte")]
public partial class BitManipulator : UserControl,
    INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BitManipulator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.grid_Items.DataContext = this;
    }


    #region Indexer and related

    public Boolean this[Int32 index]
    {
        get
        {
            return BitConverterExt.BitAt(this.BitByte, index);
        }
        set
        {
            this.BitByte = BitConverterExt.WithSetBitAt(this.BitByte, index, value);
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region Dependency properties

    public static DependencyProperty BitByteProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register
        (
            "BitByte",
            typeof(Byte),
            typeof(BitManipulator),
            new PropertyMetadata((sender, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.Property != BitByteProperty)
                        return;

                    if (args.NewValue == args.OldValue)
                        return;

                    var This = (BitManipulator)sender;

                    This.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
                })
        );

    public Byte BitByte
    {
        get { return (Byte)GetValue(BitByteProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BitByteProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        this.PropertyChanged(this,
            new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## User control xaml

To allow more easier editing I've changed TextBoxes to CheckBoxes:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid_Items">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Name="order_0" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding [0]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_1" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding [1]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_2" Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding [2]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_3" Grid.Column="3" IsChecked="{Binding [3]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_4" Grid.Column="4" IsChecked="{Binding [4]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_5" Grid.Column="5" IsChecked="{Binding [5]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_6" Grid.Column="6" IsChecked="{Binding [6]}"/>
    <CheckBox Name="order_8" Grid.Column="7" IsChecked="{Binding [7]}"/>
</Grid>
```

## Bit manipulation helper

```
public static class BitConverterExt
{
    public static Boolean BitAt(Byte byteValue, Int32 index)
    {
        if ((index < 0) || (index > 7))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Byte mask = (Byte)(0x1 << index);

        return (byteValue & mask) != 0;
    }

    public static Byte WithSetBitAt(Byte byteValue, Int32 index, Boolean value)
    {
        if ((index < 0) || (index > 7))
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Byte mask = (Byte)(0x1 << index);

        if (value)
        {
            return (Byte)(byteValue | mask);
        }

        return (Byte)(byteValue & (~mask));
    }
}
```

## Main Window code-behind (for demonstration)

Here is the main window code-behind that allows to demonstrate that any changes to either bits, user control byte or model byte property are all properly reflected.

```
public class ByteModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Byte m_ValueByte = 0xAA;

    public Byte ValueByte
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_ValueByte;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.m_ValueByte == value)
                return;

            this.m_ValueByte = value;

            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ValueByte"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ByteModel();
    }
}
```

## Main window xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <view:BitManipulator x:Name="bitManipulator" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BitByte="{Binding ValueByte, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Change model BitByte:"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding ValueByte, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
           Content="Change user control BitByte:"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
             DataContext="{Binding ElementName=bitManipulator}"
             Text="{Binding BitByte, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a multibinding to follow 3 values

```
 <ns:BitManipulator >
  <ns:BitManipulator.BitByte>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TitleSectionConverter}">
        <Binding Path="PathA" />
        <Binding Path="PathB" />
        <Binding Path="PathC" />
      </MultiBinding>
   </ns:BitManipulator.BitByte>
</ns:BitManipulator>
```

and use a converter to handle changes

```
  public class BitByteConverter : IMultiValueConverter
  {
       public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
          // implement your logic to return expected value
       }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
  }
```

The converter will be invoked after one of 3 bindings updates it source.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am not sure that it is something that OP needs. As I understand he needs some adapter collection (`INotifyCollectionChanged` wrapper over the byte property)  that will allow to project changes in the underlying byte to the bit controls and vice versa.

Comment: All three properties have the same source, so multibinding is not necessary. Actually there is only one value that will affect all mentioned properties.

Comment: But one-one binding  can only handle 1 property at one time. In that time, you must resolve others for calculation excepted value (example). With multibinding, you always have them whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `BitManipulator` control, I wouldn't use bindings. Instead, I would use simple event handlers to sync the textboxes and the bound byte:

```
<TextBox Name="order_0" Grid.Column="0" TextChanged="OnBitChanged" />
<TextBox Name="order_1" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="OnBitChanged" />
<TextBox Name="order_2" Grid.Column="2" TextChanged="OnBitChanged" />
...
```

..and:

```
public static DependencyProperty BitByteProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register
    (
        ...
        //Listen for changes in the model:
        new PropertyMetadata(OnByteChanged)
    );
```

Implementation:

```
private void OnBitChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Collect the bits from the textboxes, and create the new byte:
    byte newByte = ...

    //Update the bound model:
    this.BitByte = newByte;
}

private static void OnByteChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var manipulator = (BitManipulator)sender;
    var newByte = manipulator.BitByte;

    //Split the byte into bits and populate the textboxes:
    var bits = ...

    manipulator.order_0.Text = bits[0];
    manipulator.order_1.Text = bits[1];
    ...
}
```